# Calculating IP address from the following statement

Tags: networking, ip, subnet

I would like to not be so specific with my question, but I do not understand it and would like to get some help. The statement says:

> The interface should be addressed in the next (upwards) available /27
>   subnet in the 192.168.20.0/24 address space.

I do not understand what it means. I understand that:

*192.168.20.0/24* would mean a subnet mask of *255.255.255.0*, and the address range would be *192.168.20.0* - *192.168.20.255*. But what does the statement mean with the next upward available /27 subnet in that address space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The next /27 that's not used by something else. If 192.168.20.0/27 is available, take it. Otherwise, if 192.168.20.32/27 is available, take it. Otherwise, if 192.168.20.64/27 is available... etc. Which address within that subnet you should use, and how you determine what is "available" are both unclear from the context you gave, but probably provided somewhere.

Comment: Yes, you are right that there is some missing information here, but I thought it was not completely essential to understand my question. Now I understand it, you were pretty clear and now I know how to complete the rest. Thank you!